# Get id value of a button

Tags: php, mysql, database

This is a part of my code. I want to get the id of the button as the value of PersonID when submit is clicked. So that i can get separate id to get the value from database according to PersonID.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{   
print "<tr> <td>";

    echo $row['PersonID']; 
    print "</td> <td>";
    echo $row['FirstName']; 
    print "</td> <td>";
    echo $row['LastName']; 
    print "</td> <td>";
    echo $row['Address'];
    print "</td> <td>";
    echo "<input id=\"<?php echo $row['PersonID'];?>\" type=\"submit\" name=\"btn-signup\" value=\"Submit\">\n";

    print "</td> </tr>";


}
```

I am new to php can anyone help me with this?

Comment: rather than giving id pass into the submit button's value

Comment: echo "<input id=\"<?php echo $row['PersonID'];?>\" type=\"submit\" name=\"btn-signup\" value=\"<?php echo $row['PersonID'];?>">\n";

Comment: You can basically use string concationation with the . operator like echo '<button id="' . $row['PersonId'] . '" />

Comment: i will get get the value as the ID but i want the button to act like when i click submit it should get the whole database table value foe the same id

Comment: @stefen i did that but it shows error

Answer (score 0):

You can use curly braces within quoted text ( double quotes ) to access certain types of variables without the need for complex escaping and all that which makes it easier to write and spot errors with the escaping of quotes.

```
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result, MYSQL_ASSOC ) ){   
    echo "
    <tr>
        <td>{$row['PersonID']}</td>
        <td>{$row['FirstName']}</td>
        <td>{$row['LastName']}</td>
        <td>{$row['Address']}</td>
        <td>
            <input type='submit' name='btn-signup' value='Submit'>
            <input type='hidden' name='personID' value='{$row['PersonID']}' />
        </td>
    </tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the get the id on clicking the submit button.

Instead of following this approach, you should make it a hidden field and assign id as the value of this field.

Also, you should follow clean coding pattern and avoid writing HTML codes within echo statement. Break it up into separate HTML and PHP tags.

```
<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { ?> 
<tr> 
   <td> <?php echo $row['PersonID']; ?> </td> 
   <td> <?php echo $row['FirstName']; ?> </td> 
   <td> <?php echo $row['LastName']; ?>  </td> 
   <td> <?php echo $row['Address']; ?>   </td> 
   <td>
     <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['PersonID'];?>"> <!-- Hidden field containing ID -->
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
   </td> 
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below.

Note: Make sure you have defined `<form>` tag in your code.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {   
    print "<tr> <td>";
    echo $row['PersonID']; 
    print "</td> <td>";
    echo $row['FirstName']; 
    print "</td> <td>";
    echo $row['LastName']; 
    print "</td> <td>";
    echo $row['Address'];
    print "</td> <td>";
    echo '<input type="submit" name="btn-signup" value="Submit">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="PersonID" value="'.$row['PersonID'].'">';
    print "</td> </tr>";
}
```